# How do I set an enum value inside another enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I want something like this.

```
public enum AgeGroup  
{  
    Teenager = new enum { FromAge = 16, ToAge = 17 },  
    young = new enum { FromAge = 18, ToAge = 24  }   
}
```

By this I want access it like `AgeGroup.Teenager.FromDate`.

Comment: Enums can't be nested like that. You can make `AgeGroup` a static class though.

Comment: This cant be done, will need a class, or some other type of structure to achieve this.

Comment: And these values doesn't look like your typical enums, you sure you don't want something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nested enum is not possible.

You can change your parent enum to a class, and it will work:

```
public class AgeGroup
{
    public enum Teegaer
    {
        FromAge = 16, ToAge = 17
    }

    public enum young
    {
        FromAge = 18, ToAge = 24
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to create a **static class**:

```
public static class AgeGroup
{
   public static class TeenAge
   {
      public static readonly int FromAge = 16;
      public static readonly int ToAge = 17;
   }

  public static class YoungAge
   {
      public static readonly int FromAge = 18;
      public static readonly int ToAge = 21;
   }
}
```

Now you can refer to the variable, as below:

```
int teenAgeStarting = AgeGroup.TeenAge.FromAge  //16
int youngAgeStarting = AgeGroup.YoungAge.FromAge  //18
```

Implementation: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCGDbF)